# Hydrostatic water pressure

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics

If I have a tank of water 2 meters high x 1 meter square.
And I use a half inch outlet from the bottom of the tank going vertical, how high would the water reach in the pipe.? What would be the relationship with adding another meter in head pressure.
Or how do I calculate what I would need in head pressure given the above to reach a height of 20 feet say.

Answer (score 1):

If the pipe is going vertically up, the water in the pipe will reach the same height as the water in the tank.